# How to use If-Else conditions within spinner setOnItemSelectedListener class?

Tags: java, android

need some help here! I have a spinner which determines whether the user is a male or female. I wish to calculate bmr. If the user is a male, the bmr formula is different as compared to the female. Thus i was trying to create a textview that will display the string content of the spinner item as the variable cannot be accessed within the onItemSelected method.

So that's why i have part II where i use an if-else statement to basically compare the texts to the string and hopefully pass bmr into another activity but this isn't working as i'm getting the wrong value by default.

```
    spGender = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerGender);
    final TextView tvGender = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvGenderTemp);
    spGender.setSelection(0);

    spGender.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            tvGender.setText(item);

        }


        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserProfile.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Please select a gender!");
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
            spGender.setSelection(0);
        }
    });


    //BMR FORMULA PART II
    final double bmr;

    if ("Female".equals(tvGender.getText().toString()))

    {
        bmr = (655 + (13.7*userWeight) + (5.0*userHeight) - (6.8*userAge));
    }

    else
    {
        bmr = 66 + (13.7 * userWeight) + (1.8*userHeight) - (4.7*userAge);
    }


    Button btnUPSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUserProfileSave);
    btnUPSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent in2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CaloriesPage.class);
            in2.putExtra("mBMR",bmr);
            startActivity(in2);
        }
    });
```

Comment: try to check like `if ("Female".equalsIgnoreCase(tvGender.getText().toString()))`

Comment: Hello, the question has 2 issue here:
-  //BMR FORMULA PART II not run after you select gender ==> put it into  
`onItemSelected`
- `onNothingSelected` won't call in spinner so the dialog won't show

Comment: Thanks guys! Technically all of you guys are correct. I'd like to think that my code is correct too, just a little complicated. The reason for this was that my double variable was declared within the spinner's class and that it should be declared before the @Override like what Santosh Kumar has written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this hope this will work

```
  Spinner spGender;
    double bmr;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        List<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<>();
        spinnerArray.add("male");
        spinnerArray.add("female");
        spGender = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerGender);
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
        spGender.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        final TextView tvGender = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvGenderTemp);
        spGender.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                tvGender.setText(item);
                //BMR FORMULA PART II
                double userWeight = 10;
                double userHeight = 20;
                double userAge = 35;
                if (spGender.getSelectedItem().equals("female"))
                {
                    bmr = (655 + (13.7 * userWeight) + (5.0 * userHeight) - (6.8 * userAge));
                } else {
                    bmr = 66 + (13.7 * userWeight) + (1.8 * userHeight) - (4.7 * userAge);
                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Please select a gender!");
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
        Button btnUPSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUserProfileSave);
        btnUPSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent in2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
                in2.putExtra("mBMR", bmr);
                startActivity(in2);
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the selected item directly from spinner and compare it

```
 spGender.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        if ("Female".equals(spGender.getSelectedItem().toString())){
         bmr = (655 + (13.7*userWeight) + (5.0*userHeight) - (6.8*userAge));
        }else{
        bmr = 66 + (13.7 * userWeight) + (1.8*userHeight) - (4.7*userAge);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```

Comment: This can't work because I'm passing the variable to another activity and at the putExtra method, i get the message that bmr cannot be resolved

Comment: can you show me where you are passing and how you are doing that

Comment: I found out my mistake already. The reason why I was getting that message was because I didn't have a good practice of declaring bmr just before the @Override at OnCreate. The position of the bmr mattered a lot actually and i thought that it would be the same to declare them within the spinner's inner class

Comment: I hope now you have made the variable bmr global

Comment: Yes i have. Prior to this, i didn't exactly know how to make a variable global because i had no knowledge of java coming from C++ and there wasn't the @Override to work with!

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        tvGender.setText(item);
        if (item .equals("Female")){
            bmr = (655 + (13.7*userWeight) + (5.0*userHeight) - (6.8*userAge));
        }else{
            bmr = 66 + (13.7 * userWeight) + (1.8*userHeight) - (4.7*userAge);
        } 

 }
```